# Elasticsearch UpdateByQuery Generate Random UUID with painless

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, uuid, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

My ES version is 6.0.0.

I am trying to generate a random UUID via an update by query script. Painless simply is refusing to cooperate.

Taken from their official docs: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.0/painless-api-reference.html

```
UUID
static UUID fromString(String) (java 9)
```

My script:

```
def randText = UUID.fromString("asdadsad");
```

I get errors

```
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Unknown call [fromString] with [0] arguments on type [UUID]."
    }
```

I tried every combination possible

```
new UUID()
new UUID
UUID.random()
UUID.randomString()
UUID.randomUuid()
UUID.randomUUID()
```

How is this class supposed to work?

PS: Painless is the most painful language I've worked with.

Comment: UUIDs need to be a specific format, not just random chars.  Try `UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: `UUID.randomUUID()` gives me the following error @tim_yates
`"caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Unknown call [randomUUID] with [0] arguments on type [UUID]."
    }`

Comment: Ahhh yeah... https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/39080

Comment: Then I don't understand why they have added it into the docs for painful language

Comment: there is no randomUUID in painless api

Comment: `new Random().with{ new UUID(it.nextLong(),it.nextLong()) }`